# Fusion Table to static HTML?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a page that lists an organization's local addresses, both as an embedded Fusion Tables map, and in a table populated via Google API: http://oto-usa.org/wordpress/locations/

This is working very well, except that the Google search indexer does not "see" the informatin in either form, so e.g. a site search for "Detroit" won't return a link to this page for people trying to find our Detroit location.

What's the most straightforward way to get static HTML from a Funsion Table for search-engine fodder?

Comment: Do you want to generate the HTML table below the map with the data of your Fusion Table?

Comment: Yes. I ended up doing so by using the Google API library for PHP, and generating the map on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using the Google Fusion Tables API for PHP, generating the data on the server side and including it in the page text.